# value for an projected growth rate

Tags: mysql

i have 4 columns in databasex

```
col1=city:lagos
col2=total_population:1000
col3=growth_rate:0.22
col4=startyear:2019

$geto = " SELECT * FROM databasex WHERE city='$st' AND 
startyear='$yr'";
$gety = mysql_query($geto);
$geti = mysql_fetch_assoc($gety);
$ewe = $geti['total_population'];
$ewe1 = $geti['growth_rate'];
$ewe2 = $geti['city'];
$ewe3 = $geti['startyear'];


$inda = ceil($ewe * $ewe1/100 + $ewe);
echo number_format($inda);
```

I know this `AND startyear='$yr'`  shouldn't be.

On the front-end if i select city and year, that is next or 2years to 
    come(e.g:2020 or 2022) how do i get the value for the projected growth rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear about some details; for example what kind of full dataset could be available on the table at moment of the query execution. Assuming that you are requesting estimates for only years that do not exist on the table, then the query could be like this:

```
$geto = "SELECT * FROM databasex WHERE city='{$st}' AND startyear < '{$yr}' ORDER BY startyear DESC LIMIT 1";
```

This requests to get only one row where the year is the lowest close available than the requested.

Now, it is about the math, if you are estimating one year (e.g. requested 2020 and 2019 is available), then the calculation should be done only once, but if you are estimating more than one year (e.g. 2022 and 2019 available), you must loop through the rest of extra years from the startyear available and the year requested. Also, not sure, but that rate looks like it is already a percentage, so no need to divide it by 100 again.

Finally assuming this is PHP, do not use mysql database extension, it is deprecated. Use mysqli instead.